# Julia version 0.4.5 Openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, julia

I was using Julia version 0.3.2, I updated it to version 0.4.5. Now when I am using OpensteetMap package I am getting error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: Bounds not defined
in include at ./boot.jl:261
in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:320
in include at ./boot.jl:261
in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:320
in require at ./loading.jl:259
in include at ./boot.jl:261
in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:320
in process_options at ./client.jl:280
in _start at ./client.jl:378 while loading /home/nandani/.julia/v0.4/OpenStreetMap/src/crop.jl, 
in expression starting on line 6 while loading /home/nandani/.julia/v0.4/OpenStreetMap/src/OpenStreetMap.jl, 
in expression starting on line 38.
```

Comment: Did you try `Pkg.update()` to keep all your packages up to date?

Comment: There are a number of issues with this package  — some deprecations, problems with Winston.jl, failures connected with Tk installation too (but I always get this). Package hasn't been updated recently, or for 0.4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenStreetMap.jl](https://github.com/tedsteiner/OpenStreetMap.jl) is dependent on [Geodesy.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/Geodesy.jl/issues/14), where `Bounds` was defined. But that was [removed](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/Geodesy.jl/commit/f8480d6a90272cf5549ff01cf3152ac0752b2c2f) on April 10th. It made it into the 0.1.0 tag [7 days ago](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/Geodesy.jl/releases/tag/v0.1.0). That tag doesn't support Julia v0.3, so on Julia v0.3 you are still using the older version of Geodesy.jl, which works.

For now, as a workaround, you can pin Geodesy to the older version v0.0.1:

```
Pkg.pin("Geodesy", v"0.0.1")
```

and that should make things work on Julia v0.4.5 again.

---

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/tedsteiner/OpenStreetMap.jl/issues/85) so that this can be resolved without requiring the pin.

Comment: Indeed, you can blame me for this one. Hopefully the removed code can be easily replicated in OpenStreetMap.

Comment: @AndyF Yes, I think that's a good plan. Unfortunately it seems the maintainers of OpenStreetMap.jl aren't that active any more. Hopefully one of them reappears! Although it don't use it personally, it seems like a useful library.